# Sudoku Generator

Tags: python-2.7

So I just made a Sudoku generator that will produce 9x9 matrices. My rows, columns and sub 3x3 matrices should all follow the rules of Sudoku. Only my columns do not follow the rules. Can anyone assist? Here's my code:

```
import random 

maxAttempts = 100 #stops the program after 100 attempts
count = 9999
solCount = 0

while count > maxAttempts:
    solCount +=1
    # init array
    puzzle = []
    for i in range(9):
        row = []
        for j in range(9):
            row.append(0)
            #print row
        puzzle.append(row)

    ##for r in puzzle:
    ##    print r

    # get random value
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            thisRow=puzzle[row]
            thisCol=[]
            for h in range(9):
                thisCol.append(puzzle[row][col])

            subCol = int(col/3)
            subRow = int(row/3)
            subMat = []
            for subR in range (3):
                for subC in range (3):
                    subMat.append(puzzle[subRow*3 + subR][subCol*3 + subC])
            randVal = 0
            count = 0
            while randVal in thisRow or randVal in thisCol or randVal in subMat:
                randVal = random.randint(1,9)
                count+=1

                if count > maxAttempts: break 
            puzzle[row][col] = randVal

            if count > maxAttempts: break 
        if count > maxAttempts:
            break


for r in puzzle: print r
```

Comment: What does this have to do with R?

Comment: My apologies, accidentally clicked one of the websites autosuggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for h in range(9):
     thisCol.append(puzzle[h][col])
```

Just replace `[row]`, with `[h]` and you should be fine.